# ScrollView cuts the text in TextView

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I have a problem with my ScrollView layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/editRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/typeTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The problem is when I have a lot of text to display in TextView, TextView2 disappears... Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I don't understand how it becomes "invisible", you should still be able to scroll down and see it no matter how long the first TextView is.

Comment: yes i am able to scroll down, but i can't scroll up to see TextView2

Comment: So you can only scroll in one direction?

Comment: It is kind of hard to explain. Let it put it this way: I have a TextView2 on top with 5 lines, bellow i have TextView with 20 lines. When i Create this layout i see 5thline of TextView i can scroll to the begining (5thline) to the end and vice versa but i can't see first lines of TextView or whole TextView2 i hope there is a way to understand what i have wrote..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved the problem removing the line:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 1):

As I just stumbled across the very same problem I found a solution that allows you to keep your text centered but avoid the clipping bug:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"         // Automatic ScrollView height
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">    // Center ScrollView vertically

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="center_horizontal" /> // Center TextView content horizontally

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:layout_height` in `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

I know if you are making and EditText box there is an option to make it multiLine so that if they overflow the box it will scroll with it. I believe for TextView there is an option similar to this; on the attributes side in the android xml creator there should be an attribute to help you display without getting cut off. And yes should be wrap_content.